# Strength of Pi Donor and Acceptors as Ligands

Tags: coordination-compounds, crystal-field-theory, ligand-field-theory

The spectrochemical series is usually known as the "strength" of the ligands. It makes sense on a basic level as the more willing a ligand is to donating its electrons (via a $\sigma$-bond), the greater the repulsion on the metal's $d$-orbitals. However, I recently learned about $\pi$-donors and $\pi$-acceptors and how they affect a ligand's placement on the spectrochemical series.
$$\ce{CO > CN- > NO2- > NH3 > H2O > OH- > F- > SCN- > Cl- > Br- > I- }$$
So from the very basic spectrochemical series I have shown here, it is said that $\ce{OH-}$ is a weaker-field ligand than $\ce{H2O}$ because it can act as a $\pi$-donor, which lowers the CFSE of the d-orbitals as the $e_g$ orbitals are stabilised by the resulting bond. However, I fail to see how this translates to a lower affinity to complex with the metal. Shouldn't this make $\ce{OH-}$ more stable as a ligand? I know that this isn't the case (proven by the structure of the $\ce{[Cu(H2O)4(OH)2]}$ complex structure, $\ce{OH-}$ takes on the weaker axial position), but I don't know why.

I'll include the molecular orbital diagram I got from [chem.libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Advanced_Inorganic_Chemistry_(Wikibook)/01%3A_Chapters/1.11%3A_Pi_Donor_and_Acceptor_Ligands), which supposedly shows how the $\pi$-bonds affect ligand strength.
[image: MO diagram]